# How to specify that if a denominator should not be 0

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, notation

How can i specify in the otherwise condition of the following equation

\begin{cases}\ U & \text{if $A_{U_{Max}} = A_{U_{Min}} =$ Null},\\
\ \frac{A_{U_{Max}} - A_{U_{Min}}}{U\sqrt{2}} & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

that if denominator is 0 then make it equal to 1 ?

Comment: How about $U\sqrt{2}+\delta_{U\sqrt{2},0}$ (Kronecker's delta)?

Comment: Or $U\sqrt2+[U\sqrt2=0]$, with an [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the denominator with $ U\sqrt{2}+[U=0]$ (as suggested by Brian M. Scott) may be the shortest solution. However, keep in mind that the readers will have to mentally  process the formula  it by splitting into sub-cases anyway. So, consider refactoring the statement, e.g., *Let $F=U$ if $A_{U_{Max}} = A_{U_{Min}} = 0$, and otherwise*
$$F = \begin{cases} \frac{A_{U_{Max}} - A_{U_{Min}}}{U\sqrt{2}}, & \quad U\ne 0 \\
 \ A_{U_{Max}} - A_{U_{Min}}, & \quad U = 0
\end{cases}$$